# Best way to read 12-15GB ASCII file in C++

Tags: c++, file, memory-management

I am trying to count the number of lines in a huge file. This ASCII file is anywhere from 12-15GB. Right now, I am using something along the lines of readline() to count each line of the file. But ofcourse, this is extremely slow. I've also tried to implement a lower level reading using seekg() and tellg() but due to the size of my file, I am unable to allocate a large enough array to store each character to run a '\n' comparison (I have 8GB of ram). What would be a faster way of reading this ridiculously large file? I've looked through many posts here and most people don't seem to have trouble with the 32bit system limitation, but here, I see that as a problem (correct me if I'm wrong).

Also, if anyone can recommend me a good way of splitting something this large, that would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps memory mapping, and then just zoom through and count the line breaks.

Comment: @Kerrek: Memory mapping induces platform-specific code that has to be maintained though.

Comment: @Billy: Sure. But with a 15GB file portability is probably not your main concern :-) (Get it? *Portable*... :-S) Anyway, I'd be really curious to see the performance differences between memory mapping and chunkwise reading!

Comment: You cannot beat the physics of a hard drive with software.  This is going to take 4 minutes, at best.  If it takes a lot longer than that then you are doing it wrong or the disk is fragmented.

Comment: How does the time your current implementation takes compare with the minimum possible time it would take to read the file, based on your disk read speed? In other words, how much better could you make it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just count the lines?

Comment: @Hans: that's not really a good way to think - suddenly there can be a new solid-state drive and the disk's no longer the bottleneck, or one user's just faulted the file into OS cache and now you're attempting your line count, or you have to repeatedly run some simplistic launch or test script during RAD that internally needs to invoke the line count etc....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to read the whole file at once. If you're counting lines, just read in chunks of a given size. A couple of MB should be a reasonable buffer size.

Comment: You might have to experiment to find the optimum block size. I remember some years ago that it was smaller than expected, like less than 256K.

Comment: It can be quite large if you have a SSD, I think I've used > 1024K before

Comment: If your main concern is speed, it's better to err on the side of using a larger buffer. Thankfully, unless it's perhaps an embedded / phone / whatever app, transient usage of a couple MBs of stack just isn't significant, and there's no need to try to accurately hit that optimum point where gains have just become insignificantly small....

Comment: I am not writing for an embedded device and was trying to implement this method. Somehow it was reading much more \n's than there actually was. I will have to look further into this problem

Answer (score 4):

Try [Boost Memory-Mapped Files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html), one code for both Windows and POSIX platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Memory-mapping a file does *not* require that you actually have enough RAM to hold the whole file. I've used this technique successfully with files up to 30 GB (I think I had 4 GB of RAM in that machine). You will need a 64-bit OS and 64-bit tools (I was using Python on FreeBSD) in order to be able to address that much.

Using a memory mapped file significantly increased the performance over explicitly reading chunks of the file.

Comment: If you can't address that much, you can still map smallish sections of the file at a time. But I'm a bit confused why the questioner would have 8GB of RAM and worry about 32 bit limitations.

Comment: @Steve, maybe they haven't noticed yet that the OS is only using 3GB of it.

Comment: HxD only uses a small bit of RAM for reading files. (It reads "directly" from the disk.)

Comment: Just to expand a bit on Greg's final point: memory mapping gives a *big* performance in on Linux. On Windows, it's generally not *nearly* so positive though (in fact, it's usually one of the slower alternatives). At least the last time I tested, it was roughly neutral on one of the *BSD variants (though I can't remember which for sure).

Comment: @Steve: I am writing a 32bit application and correct me if I'm wrong but that affects the memory usage

Answer (score 0):

what OS are you on?  is there no `wc -l` or equivalent command on that platform?

Comment: Now, what OS could lack such basic facilities... *scratches head while in deep contemplation* ;-)

Comment: Not Windows: `for /f %p in (<file>) do @set /a line=line+1`

Comment: @MSalters: bet that runs like greased lightning too :-)